# Getting list of launchable installed apps - some are missing

Tags: android, android-package-managers

Here's my simple function to retrieve a list of all installed apps, I need only those that can be launched:

```
public static ArrayList<PhoneAppItem> getInstalledApps()
{
    PackageManager pm = MainApp.get().getPackageManager();
    List<PackageInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    ArrayList<PhoneAppItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < apps.size(); i++)
    {
        // nur startbare Apps hinzufügen
        if(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(i).packageName) != null)
        {
            PhoneAppItem item = new PhoneAppItem(apps.get(i).packageName);
            items.add(item);
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<PhoneAppItem>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PhoneAppItem ai1, PhoneAppItem ai2) {
            return ai1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(ai2.getName());
        }
    });

    return items;
}
```

This gives me a good result, but I'm missing some apps. Actually, I can see that I'm missing one app, the telephone app on my samsung phone (although I can see the contacts app).

Why? What would be the solution for it?

Comment: It seems that you used flag **GET_META_DATA** which is not supported by getInstalledPackages. You can check supported flags on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages(int)

Comment: "Here's my simple function to retrieve a list of all installed apps, I need only those that can be launched" -- that is not the same thing as getting all launchable activities, which is what a home screen does. For example, if an app has more than one launchable activity, your algorithm will not show the second and subsequent ones.

Comment: ok... with that information I found a solution... did not think about that. Still, now I'm looking how to find the launch intent and icon for those sub activities...

Comment: everything solved now. thanks